Using variant referances for the objects in c++
I have a template class that contains mutex and cv. I want to create different versions of this class and store it in a map with a enum key. Template class given as;
// A threadsafe-queue.
template <class T>
class SafeQueue
{
public:

  SafeQueue(void)
    : q()
    , m()
    , c()
  {}
// Copy constructor
    SafeQueue(const SafeQueue& other) : q(other.q), qCount(other.qCount), maxQCount(other.maxQCount) {}

  ~SafeQueue(void)
  {}
//other funcs...
private:
  std::queue<T> q;
  mutable std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable c;
  uint16_t qCount = 0;
  uint16_t maxQCount = 1;
};

and variant & enum defined as;
using QueueVariant = std::variant<
// Define the QueueVariant type for inputs
    SafeQueue<InputStruct>,
    SafeQueue<InputStruct2>
>;

enum class exchangeType : uint8_t{
    exch1,
    exch2
};

for the given SafeQueue<InputStruct> and SafeQueue<InputStruct2> instances ı want to create a map to hold it with its references like;
std::map<exchangeType,QueueVariant&> receiveQueueMap;

SafeQueue<InputStruct> safeQueueInstanceAlgoInput;
receiveQueueMap.emplace(exchangeType::exch1, safeQueueInstanceAlgoInput);

I get error : no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<const exchangeType, void*>::pair(exchangeType, SafeQueue<InputStruct>&)’GCC
and if I try to cast QueueVariant* like;
QueueVariant* variPtr = reinterpret_cast<QueueVariant*>(safeQueueInstanceAlgoInput);

I get invalid type conversionC/C++(171) error.
Only way I achieved to do is using copy contr on SafeQueue;
std::map<exchangeType,void*> receiveQueueMap;
SafeQueue<InputStruct> safeQueueInstanceAlgoInput;
QueueVariant vari = QueueVariant(safeQueueInstanceAlgoInput);

receiveQueueMap.emplace(exchangeType::exchMatching, (void*)&vari);

exchangeType exhType = exchangeType::exch1;
auto sendQueueIteratorInstance = receiveQueueMap.find(exhType); //iterator
auto second = sendQueueIteratorInstance->second;
QueueVariant* queueVariantPtr = reinterpret_cast<QueueVariant*>(second);

std::cout << "Variant index: " << queueVariantPtr->index() << std::endl; //This gives correct idx

but it creates a copy. I need to hold the original obj in some way.
Is there any way to hold the reference of an obj as variant reference? How to hold different template obj in a map?

would a reference wrapper solve your issue?

Well, your queue are not variants, so you'll have to create the "original object" inside the variant. I don't generally use variants, but there should be a constructor that allows you to create one of the objects directly. If I want to store different types in the same map, I usually use a common base class, as in std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<ItemBase>> items;.


I need to hold the original obj in some way.

You seem to be confused on how std::variant works. One cannot cast a pointer to T to a pointer to std::variant<T,S,Q>, those are different objects. One cannot "place" an existing object into a variant, either. When creating a variant you must create a new underlying object, at most you can use move-constructor to "move" an object state. If you're given an existing T object with its address potentially stored in some other data, you won't be able to "hold" it in a variant or an std::map. All you can do is to store the pointer to the object.

Is there any way to hold the reference of an obj as variant reference?

You can use std::variant<T*, S*, Q*> to hold pointers. If you want it to look more "reference-like" you can use std::variant<std::reference_wrapper<T>, ...> but it's not that much different from normal pointers. However, all of this may be unnecessary.

How to hold different template obj in a map?

If different template instantiations implement the same interface, inherit template from an interface class.
class ISafeQueue {
  virtual exchangeType type(void) const = 0;
  virtual void StoreDataFrom(const Storage&) = 0;
  virtual ~ISafeQueue() = default;
};

template<class T>
class SafeQueue : public ISafeQueue {
  //...
};

std::map<exchangeType, ISafeQueue*> receiveQueueMap;
//...
auto sendQueueIteratorInstance = receiveQueueMap.find(exhType); //iterator
ISafeQueue* second = sendQueueIteratorInstance->second;
//syntax-invariant logic
second->StoreDataFrom(myStorage);
//if we need to do something specific to a particular template instance:
auto* specific = dynamic_cast<SafeQueue<Something>*>(second);
specific->Add(Specific(args));

If you want the receiveQueueMap to own objects (in which case those can't be "original" objects, see above), you just use std::map<exchangeType, std::unique_ptr<ISafeQueue>> with the rest of the code pretty similar.
If there is no common interface then you have a design problem. You still can use the pattern above (with the destructor being the only virtual method) but notice that in that case, no matter what you do, you will have switches on exchangeType all over the place.
